# Take minimum one lines

Tags: data

```
x1 = 0;
y1 = 0;
x2 = Pi/4;
y2 = 0;
(* Search middle vector *)
theta1[x_, y_]:=ArcCos[Sqrt[Cos[x1]^2Cos[x]^2+Sin[x1]^2Sin[x]^2+2Cos[x1]Sin[x1]Cos[x]Sin[x]Cos[y1-y]]];
theta2[x_, y_]:=ArcCos[Sqrt[Cos[x2]^2Cos[x]^2+Sin[x2]^2Sin[x]^2+2Cos[x2]Sin[x2]Cos[x] Sin[x]Cos[y2-y]]]
Show[
ContourPlot[theta1[x, y],{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
ContourPlot[theta1[x, y] == theta2[x, y],{x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, ContourStyle -> Red],
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{x1, y1}]}],
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{x2, y2}]}]
]
```

Here is my code, and my goal is to find a point (x,y). This point (x,y) can make theta1(x,y)=theta2(x,y), and make theta1(x,y) take a minimum. theta1(x,y) and theta2(x,y) are functions defined in the code, and 0 < x < pi, 0 < y < pi.

My code can help me find the point I want. For example,

```
ContourPlot[theta1[x, y] == theta2[x, y]]
```

can draw two lines, and all points on the lines satisfy theta1(x,y)=theta2(x,y).

Then I use

```
ContourPlot[theta1[x, y]
```

to find which point one the lines can make theta1 take a minimum. As shown in the figure. The green point is what I'm looking for.

[image]

The problem is I need to obtain the (x,y) by eyes! Is there any other possible methods to get the coordinate of (x,y) directly?

Comment: Try `NMinimize[{theta1[x, y], theta1[x, y] == theta2[x, y]}, {x, y}]`

Comment: Excellent!! Mathematica is so powerful!

Answer (score 1):

You can minimize the function `theta1` directly using constraints:

```
sol = NMinimize[{theta1[x, y], theta1[x, y] == theta2[x, y], 0 < x < Pi, 
  0 < y < Pi}, {x, y}]
```

> {0.392699, {x -> 0.392699, y -> 0.}}

```
{x0, y0} = {x, y} /. sol[[2]]
```

> {0.392699, 0.}

```
min = sol[[1]]
```

> 0.392699

```
a = theta1[x, y] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0};
b = theta2[x, y] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0};
a - b
```

> -1.41054*10^-8

Comment: How to extract the results? for example, give 0.39 to x0 and 0 to y0? Because I need to use these number to do further calculation.

Comment: @QiZhong See edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = 0;
y1 = 0;
x2 = Pi/4;
y2 = 0;
theta1[x_, y_] := 
  ArcCos[Sqrt[
    Cos[x1]^2 Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x1]^2 Sin[x]^2 + 
     2 Cos[x1] Sin[x1] Cos[x] Sin[x] Cos[y1 - y]]];
theta2[x_, y_] := 
 ArcCos[Sqrt[
   Cos[x2]^2 Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x2]^2 Sin[x]^2 + 
    2 Cos[x2] Sin[x2] Cos[x] Sin[x] Cos[y2 - y]]]

sys = {theta1[x, y], theta1[x, y] == theta2[x, y],
   0 < x < Pi, 0 < y < Pi};

sol1 = NMinimize[sys, {x, y}]

(*  {0.392699, {x -> 0.392699, y -> 0.}}  *)
```

Checking whether the conditions are satisfied

```
Rest[sys] /. sol1[[2]]

(*  {False, True, False}  *)
```

Note that the solution does not satisfy the condition `theta1[x,y]==theta2[x,y]` nor `0<y<Pi` to the required tolerance.  Increasing the [**`WorkingPrecision`**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) will give the other result and satisfies the conditions.

```
sol2 = NMinimize[sys, {x, y}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(*  {0.39269908169872415481, {x -> 2.7488935718910690837, 
  y -> 3.1415926533031383622}}  *)

Rest[sys] /. sol2[[2]]

(*  {True, True, True}  *)
```

The coordinates of the point are

```
pt = {x, y} /. sol2[[2]]

(*  {2.7488935718910690837, 3.1415926533031383622}  *)
```